# Why is this answer getting downvoted?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I just need some help or an explaination on what is the wrong with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644587/4171008.

How I can improve it in order not to get another downvote?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong to me...

Comment: If there is some way to know who down-voted it and ask him/her why... it is bad to get down-vote for no reason or explaining

Comment: There deliberately is not to prevent harassment or retaliatory voting.

Comment: Perhaps because you mispelled "becuase"?

Comment: I can't speak for the accuracy of the answer so I'm only offering a possibility, but given the question was closed because it is "unclear", it is not uncommon to see downvotes on answers to questions that are unclear or vague because they are nothing more than guesses as to what the problem is.  But why your answer was downvoted and not the other doesn't really support this idea.

Comment: I was joking, of course, but seriously, I agree with @psubsee2003 -- sometimes answers are DV'd for low-quality questions. Fair or not -- who knows, but one DV doesn't mean much in this world.

Comment: Why did you add `a_out = sess.run(a)` and not `a_out = sess.run(e)` and do note they assign `a_out` later again. Not sure if that is fine but that might be confusing as well. At least it is for me with no knowledge in the topic of that question.

Comment: I work with Python and know where or what is the error, and this code is from the basics, so I was not guessing

Comment: @rene in the code above form the post you can see he is printing variable `a` so you use `a` in the method calling

Comment: You got the acceptance; you're ahead of the game. Move on.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I know I must move on but a guy like me with Rep 996 the downvote effect on me not like the others with 1K and more and that's the reason of my asking.

Comment: A few more good questions/answers, or a bit of grinding in review queues editing questions and you'll have enough rep to be solidly in the >1k rep class and not have to worry for a while.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can really improve that answer - it will stay "not useful" for future visitors pretty much with any edits. There is really no reason to answer spelling mistake questions as answers - a comment would be enough.

The only thing that may make it marginally better is to change "because it's not written right:" (that sounds like some real problem that needs to be fixed) into "you misspell `.global_variables_initializer`".

For the second problem (undeclared variable) I seriously doubt that *no one ever* asked about it in Python... Again comment/duplicate would be better option.